# Verb to use when your finger are being "pushed" by the current of a stream?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What's the adequate verb to use to describe the current of a stream "pushing" your fingers downstream as you immerse them in it? Like for example:

> I immersed my fingers in the stream. Its current [...] them
>   vigorously.

I also thought of "dragged" but I think that implies they are being washed away?

Comment: How about *pulled* or *tugged at*?

Comment: If an entire object or person were being carried by the current you would use the verb "swept" but I don't think that fits this usage.

Comment: *Its* current, not *it's*

Comment: I would just use either pushed or pulled.

Comment: Consider *thrust*: "push (something or someone) in the specified direction."

Answer (score 1):

How about [*buffeted*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buffeting)<sup>2</sup>?

> 1. To hit or beat, especially repeatedly.
> 2. To strike against forcefully; batter: winds that buffeted the tent. See Synonyms at beat.
> 3. To drive or force with or as if with repeated blows: was buffeted about from job to job by the vagaries of the economy.

And, as I mentioned in a comment, you need *its*, not *it's*.

> I immersed my fingers in the stream. Its current buffeted them vigorously.

I prefer combining them:

> I immersed my fingers in the stream, its current buffeting them vigorously.

Comment: _Buffet_ is far stronger than what the OP is after. It brings to mind your hand being banged against the banks and would not need _vigorously_ since it's pretty vigorous to begin with. I would also not recommend combining them as you have since that mixes up the tenses (_I immersed_ and _buffeting_) which seems clumsy in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[rippled](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ripple) around*

> a slight wave or undulation on the surface of water

Comment: That's poetic, but I wouldn't exactly call it a common usage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm with starwed.  I'd go with the obvious, either pushed or pushed against.